# Java 9 Stream iterate method ignores the last element of the stream

Tags: java, java-stream, java-9

Regarding the [Java 9 Stream iterate method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)), I am unsure about the order of execution of the `Predicate` and `UnaryOperator` methods.

Consider the following example:

```
Stream<BigInteger> streamIterate = Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ZERO, n -> n.intValue() < 100, n -> n.add(BigInteger.ONE));
streamIterate.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The values being printed go from **0** to **99** and this is what confused me.

If the first stream element is `seed`, and all the other elements are being added if the condition is satisfied for the current element, that means that when we add value of **99** to the stream it becomes the current element, the `hasNext` condition is satisfied and we should expect to have **100** as the last value, before the stream ends.

However, the stream ends with **99**.

Comment: *all the other elements are being added if the condition is satisfied for the current element*... That's wrong. They're added if it's satisfied for the *next* element. Hence the name `hasNext`.

Comment: @shmosel actually, I can understand the OP’s confusion. The phrase “has next” is not sufficient to describe the logic, as it could mean “has [this element a] next [element]” whereas it is supposed to mean “has [this stream the specified] next [element]”. You read that into the `hasNext` name only if you already understood the intended meaning.

Comment: As a side note, you’d prefer `IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)` for most practical purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate that you have will only allow upto and including `99` to be printed.  `Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ZERO, n -> n.intValue() < 100, n -> n.add(BigInteger.ONE))` is equivalent to, `for (BigInteger n = BigInteger.ZERO; n.intValue() < 100; n.add(BigInteger.ONE))`.

Here is a simpler example, from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-stream-api),

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i < 10, i -> i + 1)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

is equivalent to,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

which would only print, `0` through `9`.

Answer (score 4):

According to [`Stream.iterate(seed, hasNext, next)` doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)):

> Returns a sequential ordered Stream produced by iterative application of the given next function to an initial element, conditioned on satisfying the given hasNext predicate. **The stream terminates as soon as the hasNext predicate returns false.**

So `100` is not satisfying the `n.intValue() < 100` predicate and it will not be printed